# can't find Objects using pubmed.mineR package

Tags: r, pubmed

I have downloaded abstracts of interest from pubmed.com then read them using pubmed.mineR package with readabs() function. which is supposed to create object of class "Abstracs", but when I type in ls(), it gives me character(0).
I want to search abstracts using searchabsL(Object,include="protein"),though i don't know how?

Comment: mystery solved 
x = readabs("downloaded file")

Answer (score 1):

mystery solved `x = readabs("downloaded file")`
thanks Dr.Ramachandran for providing the answer.